# VBA ADO Insert failing silently (no errors)

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, ado

I have a really frustrating issue.  I have an insert query that will run fine if you run it from within access (takes ~ 2 minutes to complete) but when I try to run it programatically from Excel via ADO, the .execute line actions in seconds with no errors, but does not actually insert any data to the table.

The ADO I use is below:

```
With objCommand
    .ActiveConnection = p_moConn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "[" & strQueryName & "]"
    .Execute
End With
```

I have also tried:

```
p_moConn.Execute strSQL, adCmdText
```

With exactly the same result.  (strQueryName is the name of the saved procedure, strSQL is the raw SQL)

BTW, before we get into it, i'm not using DAO as this is a prototype that will be migrated from Access to a "main" database system and the only code change necessary *should* be the connection string... fingers crossed...

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Matt

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery perhaps?

Comment: Can you show us the Dim for objCommand and p_moConn? In the mean time I will try and find some code from years back that would look into ADO errors that were not reported. And is your connection to SQL Server?

Comment: Hey, so not sure what ExecuteNonQuery is, i've not heard of it before. This is (at present) an Excel front end connecting to an Access back end. As I said though, that will change in the future, hence ADO usage etc, but this is for proof of concept blah blah ;-) It is only 5 of 43 queries that this happens with and the 43 run in a loop, so all pass through the same ADO execution code, so my current route of investigation is to try and find what makes those 5 different... Dim objCommand As ADODB.Command Private p_moConn As ADODB.Connection THANKS!!!

Comment: Can you post the SQL in strQueryName ?

Answer (score 0):

Cheers for the help, it was something to do with those 5 queries.  I can't post the SQL (apart from anything else it is long...) but because of the length and complexity Access was "fiddling" with it internally.  Namely it added something to the very end of the query:

```
AS [%$##@_Alias];
```

When I change that to:

```
AS [test];
```

The ADO code runs it perfectly!  As an aside, I believe the reason I was getting no error was because I was looking at the VBA Error object and not the ADO one which I think it found in:

```
.ActiveConnection.Errors()
```

But that is untested

Thanks again guys!

Matt

BTW, I found this thanks to Wayne G. Dunn as when I looked at the code to see if I could sanitize it before posting I finally noticed the last line that Access had changed... so cheers ;-)